# I am looking for kind of popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I am looking in google for some kind of popup. Lets say when i press on something a little cloud will appear and it disapears after few seconds or wherever i click.
How is that called?? All popup/modal window scripts in google are big like screen size, make the rest of page disapear or require pressing X to close it.
What should I type in google to find something like this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should start here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: All you are really looking for is to make a DIV appear.  Just look up how to make a DIV appear, and position is absolutely where you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make a div and set with display:none; and z-index:99999;
To show the popup you can use jquery.show(). 
Something like that:

**HTML CODE:**

```
 <html>
      <body>
    <div id="popup">
      <p>popup content</p>
      <button type="button" id="closePopup">Close D:</button>
    </div>
    <p>This is the content of the website</p>
    <button type="button" id="openPopup">Open popup :D</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  background-color:#ddd;
}

#popup{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  border:1px solid #444;
  position:absolute;
  margin:20px 0px 0px 300px;
  background-color:#222;
  color:#ddd;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px 1px #444;
  z-index:99999;
  display:none;
}
```

**JS (jQuery)**

```
$('#openPopup').click(function(event){
  $('#popup').show();
});

$('#closePopup').click(function(event){
  $('#popup').hide();
});
```

[Link to codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JobPMX)

excuse my por english.